# Disable Raspbian gui and boot straight into application

Tags: raspbian, boot, java

I have a jar file I am trying to run without the raspbian os. Basically just boot straight into the application. I have my commands to run the jar file in /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart. Is there any way i can disable the gui and have that application startup script to still run. Also the application runs chromium browser to view the application on local host. I apologize if this is a basic or stupid question in advance.

Comment: You cannot run a jar file without first loading some OS. Do you really mean that you don't want to run the OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible with Raspberry because the script

`/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`

is loaded by LXDE which is GUI. Also, you have chosen the wrong file to start your application. It should be

`/home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`

Even if you made some changes in `xinit` files and stopped `LXDE` to load. Then your `jar` file won't be able to open `chromium` because there will be no `X display` running.

Answer (score 0):

- First you need to `disable` login to Desktop and `enable` login to console.
- Now make your file executable (Search the internet there are plenty of tutorials)
- Now edit the `rc.local` file: `sudo nano /etc/rc.local`
- Add these lines before exit0:

  `export DISPLAY=:0`

  `startx /path/to/your/file`
- Now reboot

Your app will now open without loading the Desktop